# Catch keypress document wide and start typing in search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I want to catch all key presses on my webpage so that when you start typing the text appears in the search box (input) and this box gets focus.

Can someone provide me some hints?

Comment: What about using search in stackoverflow?

Comment: Thanx. I thought I had to do some extra to add the key to the search box, but it is this simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

Since you tagged your question with `jquery`, here you go:

```
var $search = $("#search");

$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (!$search.is(":focus"))
    if (e.which != 9 && e.which != 13)
      $search.focus();
});
```

The `.focus()` function to set the focus to the input field won't be called if the focus is already set. The input field also won't be selected if the user pressed the `tab` or `enter` key!

**Accessibility**

If someone tries to use your website without a mouse (just with keyboard), he won't be able to navigate anywhere. Maybe you have to consider to use additional techniques like the HTML's [tabindex](http://webdesign.about.com/od/usability/a/aa071105.htm).

Comment: Thanx. I thought I had to do some extra to add the key to the search box, but it is this simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery like below

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    $("id-of-input-box").focus()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to implement this feature on my website, but only when the user presses `s` (s for search) and I didn't want it to trigger if the focus was already in another input box. Here's my solution:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    // :input applies to input, select, textarea, etc.
    if (!$(':input').is(":focus")) {

        if (!$('input[name=query]').is(":focus")) {
            var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

            if (key == 83) { // if 's'
                $('input[name=query]').focus();
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Credit to @Wolle whose answer I used to get started.